# Flutter GestureDetector is not capturing gestures if it's child is handling them

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector

I have following widget:

```
GestureDetector(
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
//  behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
  onTap: (() {
    print('gesture detector tap');
  }),
  onLongPress: (() {
    print(
        'gesture detector longPress');
  }),
  child: ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {
      print('button pressed');
    },
    onLongPress: () {
      print('button long pressed');
    },
    child: Text('I am button'),
  ),
);
```

No matter if I go with `HitTestBehavior.translucent` or `HitTestBehavior.opaque` or `HitTestBehavior.deferToChild` it is always ONLY ElevatedButton's events that are fired.

Why is it like that?

I believe that with `HitTestBehavior.opaque` the GestureDetector should "intercept" the gestures, right?

Comment: I think this [answer](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18450#issuecomment-397372078) is what you're looking for

Answer (score 2):

Try replace GestureDetector on:

```
Listener(
    behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
    onPointerDown: ..,
    onPointerUp: ..,
..)
```

Answer (score 0):

The flutter documentation for `HitTestBehavior` is wrong at worst and misleading at best and needs to be updated: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/74733

Even the flutter team seems to be confused what exactly is happening.

But in this case, `opaque` does not do what you think it should do. Instead you need `AbsorbPointer` to stop the child from getting hit.

```dart
GestureDetector(
    child: AbsorbPointer(
        ...
    )
)
```